# Fancyhdr Footer not showing, how to fix this?

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\geometry{a4paper,top=0.5in,left=0.50in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.50in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{80pt}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{header.png}}
\fancyfoot[LO,LE]{PRINT NAME: FirstName LastName}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{SIGNATURE: \includegraphics[height=30pt]{footer.png}}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{Date: \today}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it a Minimum Working Example (in the sense that other users can just copy-paste, build, and see what the output looks like and what errors there are).

Comment: Remove `\setlength{\footskip}{80pt}` or set it to a lower value than `0.55in` because you defined in your `\geometry`-command the bottom to be `0.55in`.

Comment: @Nico Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: I have added an answer because it would be too much for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MWE based on your code compiles for me and produces an output as I would expect it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tabto, fancyhdr, graphicx, geometry, blindtext}
\geometry{a4paper,top=0.5in,left=0.50in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.50in}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\includegraphics[height=30pt]{example-image-a}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{PRINT NAME: FirstName LastName}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{SIGNATURE: \includegraphics[height=30pt]{example-image-b.png}}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{Date: \today}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]